# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS STARTUP taking too long because of cloud-init / url_helper.py issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, cloud-init

Everytime I restart my server I get this cloud-init related error that slows the startup by 5 minutes.
Where this error comes from and how can I fix this?

```
[    5.458859] cloud-init[869]: Cloud-init v. 22.1-14-g2e17a0d6-0ubuntu1~20.04.3 running 'init-local' at Sat, 09 Apr 2022 03:53:54 +0000. Up 5.34 seconds.
[    5.461936] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:53:54,863 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [0/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[    6.460323] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:53:55,864 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [1/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[    7.462202] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:53:56,866 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [2/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[    8.463907] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:53:57,868 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [3/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[    9.466026] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:53:58,870 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [4/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   10.467623] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:53:59,871 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [5/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   12.470406] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:01,874 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [7/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   14.472911] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:03,877 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [9/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   16.475218] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:05,879 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [11/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   18.478773] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:07,883 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [13/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   20.481622] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:09,885 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [15/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   23.485339] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:12,889 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [18/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   26.489060] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:15,893 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [21/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   29.492793] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:18,896 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [24/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   32.496441] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:21,900 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [27/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   35.499969] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:24,904 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [30/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   39.505595] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:28,909 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [34/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   43.510386] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:32,914 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [38/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   47.516312] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:36,919 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [42/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   51.520940] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:40,925 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [46/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   55.526099] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:44,929 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [50/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   60.531079] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:49,935 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [55/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   65.536969] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:54,941 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [60/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   70.543584] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:54:59,947 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [65/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   75.549952] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:04,953 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [70/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   80.554855] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:09,959 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [75/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   86.561869] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:15,965 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [81/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   92.568689] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:21,972 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [87/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[   98.575353] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:27,979 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [93/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  104.581833] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:33,986 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [99/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  110.589199] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:39,992 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [105/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  117.596895] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:47,000 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [112/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  124.604726] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:55:54,008 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [119/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  131.612012] cloud-init[869]: 2022-04-09 03:56:01,016 - DataSourceEc2.py[WARNING]: IMDS's HTTP endpoint is probably disabled
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-init job (pre-networking)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork (Pre)[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Service[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Service[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mWait for Network to be Configured[0m...
         Starting [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started [0;1;39mNetwork Name Resolution[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mHost and Network Name Lookups[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mWait for Network to be Configured[0m.
         Starting [0;1;39mInitial cloud-ini… (metadata service crawler)[0m...
[  134.126690] cloud-init[922]: Cloud-init v. 22.1-14-g2e17a0d6-0ubuntu1~20.04.3 running 'init' at Sat, 09 Apr 2022 03:56:03 +0000. Up 134.08 seconds.
[  134.129254] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[  134.131165] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +--------+------+------------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[  134.133074] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address            |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
[  134.135367] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +--------+------+------------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[  134.137354] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |  ens5  | True |         172.31.72.80         | 255.255.240.0 | global | 16:86:10:06:d1:7b |
[  134.139201] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |  ens5  | True | fe80::1486:10ff:fe06:d17b/64 |       .       |  link  | 16:86:10:06:d1:7b |
[  134.141148] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1           |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
[  134.143015] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128            |       .       |  host  |         .         |
[  134.144955] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +--------+------+------------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
[  134.146804] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[  134.148558] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[  134.150148] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: | Route | Destination |   Gateway   |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags |
[  134.151882] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[  134.153532] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   | 172.31.64.1 |     0.0.0.0     |    ens5   |   UG  |
[  134.155166] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   1   | 172.31.64.0 |   0.0.0.0   |  255.255.240.0  |    ens5   |   U   |
[  134.156870] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   2   | 172.31.64.1 |   0.0.0.0   | 255.255.255.255 |    ens5   |   UH  |
[  134.158488] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
[  134.160173] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
[  134.161483] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[  134.162778] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
[  134.164191] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[  134.165499] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   1   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    ens5   |   U   |
[  134.166837] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   3   |    local    |    ::   |    ens5   |   U   |
[  134.168247] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: |   4   |  multicast  |    ::   |    ens5   |   U   |
[  134.169557] cloud-init[922]: ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
[  134.170885] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:03,530 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [0/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  135.128814] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:04,532 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [1/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  136.130722] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:05,534 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [2/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  137.132591] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:06,536 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [3/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  138.134159] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:07,538 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [4/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  139.136039] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:08,540 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [5/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  141.138877] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:10,543 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [7/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  143.141259] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:12,545 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [9/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  145.144132] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:14,548 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [11/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  147.146866] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:16,550 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [13/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  149.149246] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:18,553 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [15/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  152.152800] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:21,556 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [18/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  155.156223] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:24,560 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [21/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  158.160763] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:27,565 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [24/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  161.164337] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:30,568 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [27/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  164.168144] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:34,122 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [30/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  168.172608] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:38,126 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [34/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  172.177107] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:42,131 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [38/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  176.181797] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:46,135 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [42/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  180.186514] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:50,140 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [46/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  184.191532] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:54,145 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [50/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  189.196838] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:56:59,150 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [55/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  194.202670] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:04,156 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [60/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  199.208055] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:09,162 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [65/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  204.213959] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:14,167 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [70/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  209.219749] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:19,173 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [75/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  215.226638] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:25,180 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [81/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  221.233325] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:31,187 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [87/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  227.239863] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:37,194 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [93/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  233.246984] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:43,200 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [99/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  239.253433] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:49,207 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [105/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  246.261211] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:57:56,215 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [112/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  253.268705] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:58:03,222 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token' failed [119/120s]: request error [Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token]
[  260.276007] cloud-init[922]: 2022-04-09 03:58:10,229 - DataSourceEc2.py[WARNING]: IMDS's HTTP endpoint is probably disabled
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-ini…ob (metadata service crawler)[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mCloud-config availability[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork is Online[0m.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Initialization[0m.
```

My EC2 VM version is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-1021-aws x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to reach some metadata over the cloud init service and can't reach the metadata service, so it keeps trying for all the entries. You can disable the cloud init service in the following file:

```
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_dpkg.cfg
```

use the following command to make it to point to nothing:

```
echo 'datasource_list: [ None ]' | sudo -s tee /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_dpkg.cfg
```

and then the following, in order to reconfigure the cloud init package:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive cloud-init
```

However if you want to get it back to defaults, you can use the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_dpkg.cfg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive cloud-init
```

Comment: I tried all the steps you mentioned and it didn't work... I've just reboot the machine, selected only "None" and "EC2" and the error persists, it cannot retrieve the EC2 metadata, even though I tested and the endpoint is reachable after the machine finally completes the reboot.
`[   46.625425] cloud-init[483]: 2023-08-10 20:35:40,283 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Exception(s) [UrlError('Failed to parse: http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token'), UrlError('Failed to parse: http://[fd00:ec2::254]/latest/api/token')] during request to http://[fd00:ec2::254]/latest/api/token, raising last exception`

Answer (score 0):

In cloud-init configuration of your EC2 instance , some command is trying to get token which might be used for necessary function, but metadata seems disabled on your ec2 instance.

You can verify whether metadata is enabled or not by below command from your ec2 instance.

```
curl -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

If it doesn't give any metadata of instance, it is disabled. You can enable by below command using aws ec2 commandline tool.

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options --instance-id {{instance_id}} --http-endpoint enabled
```

Verify whether metadata is enable again and cloud-init command works to get token. After that booting instance won't take much time.

Comment: I executed the command "curl -v http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/" and it returned the metadata list "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" , so it's not disabled... the problem is in something else. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please also post cloud-init data here for further investigation ?

Comment: Sure, here it is [cloud-init logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M_NemL9TYft-Hn9cZXEpS0BL6ksSCy80/view?usp=sharing) and also the [GitHub issue link](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/issues/4316)